# Python requests post json raw data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, request, python-requests

How to post RAW DATA using Resuests lib on python?
I'm trying to login.

**Json throwing Exception**

TypeError: set(['"clienteLogin":{"Token":"b94261f7e6744380919d406f576110cc","Operador":"","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"PalavraCaptcha":"","Senha":"muranga21","cadastro":"on","Email":"xazune@car101.pro"},"mesclarCarrinho":true,"Token":"b94261f7e6744380919d406f576110cc","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"Operador":""}']) is not JSON serializable

**Body raw(Postman)**

{"clienteLogin":{"Token":"cbf36fb0e3de4b65ab0037303979a806","Operador":"","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"PalavraCaptcha":"","Senha":"muranga21","cadastro":"on","Email":"xazune@car101.pro"},"mesclarCarrinho":true,"Token":"cbf36fb0e3de4b65ab0037303979a806","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"Operador":""}

**Code**

```
import requests,json
import cookielib
from lxml import html



s = requests.session()
req1 = s.get("https://carrinho.extra.com.br/Checkout?ReturnUrl=http://www.extra.com.br#login")
content1 = req1.content
tree = html.fromstring(content1)
token = tree.xpath("//script")[0].text.split('"')[1]
data = {
'"clienteLogin":{"Token":"'+token+'","Operador":"","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"PalavraCaptcha":"","Senha":"muranga21","cadastro":"on","Email":"xazune@car101.pro"},"mesclarCarrinho":true,"Token":"'+token+'","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"Operador":""}'
 }
headers = {
'Content-Type':'application/json'
}

req3 = s.post("https://carrinho.extra.com.br/Api/checkout/Cliente.svc/Cliente/Login",json.dumps(data),headers=headers)

print req3.content
```

Comment: `data` can be string or python dictionary and requests converts it into string. You create `set()` because `{}` is also used to create `set()` if you doesn't use keys and values inside.

Comment: I'm new on python what i need to do to fix?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use string without `{}`

```
data = '{"clienteLogin":"Token":"'+token+'","Operador":"","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"PalavraCaptcha":"","Senha":"muranga21","cadastro":"on","Email":"xazune@car101.pro"},"mesclarCarrinho":true,"Token":"'+token+'","IdUnidadeNegocio":5,"Operador":""}'
```

or dictionary and `requests` will convert it into string.

```
data = {
    "clienteLogin": {
        "Token": token,
        "Operador": "",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio": 5,
        "PalavraCaptcha": "",
        "Senha": "muranga21",
        "cadastro": "on",
        "Email": "xazune@car101.pro"
    },
    "mesclarCarrinho": True,
    "Token": token,
    "IdUnidadeNegocio": 5,
    "Operador":"",
}
```

---

**EDIT:** you don't need `json.dumps()` and `header` - `requests` has `json=`

```
data = {
    "clienteLogin": {
        "Token": token,
        "Operador": "",
        "IdUnidadeNegocio": 5,
        "PalavraCaptcha": "",
        "Senha": "muranga21",
        "cadastro": "on",
        "Email": "xazune@car101.pro"
    },
    "mesclarCarrinho": True,
    "Token": token,
    "IdUnidadeNegocio": 5,
    "Operador":"",
}

url = "https://carrinho.extra.com.br/Api/checkout/Cliente.svc/Cliente/Login"
req3 = s.post(url, json=data)

print(req3.json())
```

Result:

```
{'EfetuarLoginResult': {'DataNascimentoAno': '1984', ... }
```

---

**BTW:** `req3.json()` converts to python dictionary

```
data = req3.json()

print(data['EfetuarLoginResult']['DataNascimentoAno'])
```

Comment: `requests` has `json=`  
Thank you!!! I was messing around with all these old recommendations and stumbed on your answer.  That info was key. 

Answer (score 1):

You have enclosed your `data` variable in single quotes. Remove them and just use a standard dict.